# Is there evidence that the ancient Persians debated every matter once sober and once drunk?

Tags: cultural-history, persia

An interesting comment on [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/98729/if-everyone-in-the-senate-is-drunk-does-that-invalidate-their-actions) question led me to investigate the claim that the ancient Persians would debate every matter once whilst drunk, and once whilst sober (with no particular emphasis on which should come first), upon the presumption that a truly good decision should stand up under both conditions.

C.S. Lewis was the first thread down this line, and he does appear to have written the following in "Letters to Malcolm: Chiefly on Prayer"

> I know this is the opposite of what is often said about the necessity of keeping all emotion out of our intellectual processes – ‘you can’t think straight unless you are cool.’ But then neither can you think deep if you are. I suppose one must try every problem in both states. You remember that the ancient Persians debated everything twice: once when they were drunk and once when they were sober.

I traced this sentiment as I could, and discovered that it appears to originate with Herodotus in his Histories 1 verse(?) 133, as follows in Macaulay's translation.

> To wine-drinking [the Persians] are very much given, and it is not permitted for a man to vomit or to make water in presence of another. Thus do they provide against these things; and they are wont to deliberate when drinking hard about the most important of their affairs, and whatsoever conclusion has pleased them in their deliberation, this on the next day, when they are sober, the master of the house in which they happen to be when they deliberate lays before them for discussion: and if it pleases them when they are sober also, they adopt it, but if it does not please them, they let it go: and that on which they have had the first deliberation when they are sober, they consider again when they are drinking.

However, I am no specialist in the history of the Middle East, modern or ancient, and I have failed in attempts to follow the thread any further than this.

So, if you might help me, **is there any other supporting data or proof that the ancient Persians made sure to debate important issues once sober and once drunk?**

Comment: IMHO, this devolves to the question "Are there any earlier references saying this was A Thing?"

Comment: @T.E.D. Isn't it equally the -- quite valid -- question of "Did This Thing actually happen and, if so, how do we know?"

Comment: @MarkOlson - ...both of which devolve to "Are there any earlier references ...?"

Comment: &T.E.D. Archeological finds, fragmentary inscriptions, later traditions and the like, while each by itself completely inconclusive, can add up to support -- or dissupport -- for a theory. Also, a later history which appears to be independent of Herodotus would provide valuable evidence. While the earliest reference is likely to be the most valuable, it's rarely by itself determinant and can even be falsified by the weight of other evidence. (But I suspect we're quibbling. I only pushed back because I feel that we're a bit too quick to dismiss interesting questions.)

Comment: Did you find any evidence in your research anywhere else of his custom?

Comment: @T.E.D., not the OP, but I'd also accept a Herodotus-contemporary but independent source for the claim.